# How to convert array indices into possible moves for a rook and bishop chess piece

Tags: java, arrays, chess

I'm struggling to work out how to convert index numbers in a 2D array into possible moves for a rook and bishop to move. I want to get a boolean expression to see if a move is legal. Sorry, I'm new to programming, I'd really appreciate some help

for the rook, I have

```
if(Math.abs(xTo-xFrom)>1 &&. Math.abs(yTo-yFrom)==0){ }
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: for the rook, 

if(Math.abs(xTo-xFrom)>1  &&. Math.abs(yTo-yFrom)==0){
}

Comment: OK, that is a logical statement and it looks like your on the right path in terms of logic. but that statement is not alone is a program. do you have a main class? how are you running it? What is the error you are seeing? what is it doing that its not supposed to do? please update the question with these details -- these details are crucial to get a good SO reply

Comment: Yes, please show the code you have tried in your post itself (use the "edit" button) and explain how it fails so that we can help you with a specific issue. Currently, there's no question in your.. question

Comment: looks like you have an unnecessary `.` after `&&`; does your expression have any problems aside that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rook moves horizontally and vertically. So either the `x` coordinate changes with the `y` remaining unchanged, or the `y` coordinate changes with the `x` coordinate remaining unchanged.

`if ((xFrom != xTo) && (yFrom == yTo) || (xFrom == xTo) && (yFrom != yTo))`

Alternatively, you can use an exclusive OR (XOR), which is essentially the same thing as above just more concise.

`if ((xFrom != xTo) ^ (yFrom != yTo))`

An XOR returns true if one of them is true, but not both.

Remember that the Rook also has a special Castling move with the King, which you will need to cater for depending on the state of the game (both the rook and king haven't moved, the king is not in check, etc.)

The bishop moves diagonally, so the difference between xFrom and xTo must be the same as the difference between yFrom and yTo, in both directions.

So this should do the trick for the bishop:

`if (Math.abs(xTo - xFrom) == Math.abs(yTo - yFrom))`

Of course there is much more to both the Rook and Bishop. You have to make sure that the path is clear up till the destination coordinate, you have to make sure that the destination coordinate is not occupied by a piece of the same player, and you have to check that the move does not put the king of the same player in check (which you have to do anyway for any piece move).

Comment: Castling is a king move, not a rook move, so it would most likely be handled separately from the logic of a rook move.

Comment: @jsheeran Well implement it as you wish I guess. Just keep it in mind as another possibility.

Comment: @sheenareid please accept the answer if it is correct